# I am trying to convert this EJS JavaScript to React for a portfolio site I am building (beginner)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ejs

Here is the original code I wrote for a coffee calculator app

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require("ejs");
const app = express();

let brewTypeResult = '';
let cupQuantityResult = '';
let gramsOfWater = 0;
let gramsOfCoffee = 0;
let grindType = '';
let stepOne = '';
let stepTwo = '';
let stepThree = '';
let stepFour = '';
let stepFive = '';

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render("input");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  const brewType = req.body.brewType;
  const cupQuantity = req.body.cupQuantity;

  console.log("brew type: " + brewType);
  console.log("cups: " + cupQuantity);

  brewTypeResult = brewType;
  cupQuantityResult = cupQuantity;

  res.redirect("/results");

  switch (brewTypeResult) {
    case 'Filter':
      grindType = 'Medium'
      gramsOfWater = cupQuantity * 235
      gramsOfCoffee = cupQuantity * 14
      stepOne = 'f1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepTwo = 'f2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepThree = 'f3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepFour = 'f4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepFive = 'f5- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      break;
    case 'French Press':
      grindType = 'Coarse'
      gramsOfWater = cupQuantity * 350
      gramsOfCoffee = cupQuantity * 30
      stepOne = 'fp1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepTwo = 'fp2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepThree = 'fp3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepFour = 'fp4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepFive = 'fp5- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      break;
    case 'V60':
      grindType = 'Medium-Coarse'
      gramsOfWater = cupQuantity * 250
      gramsOfCoffee = cupQuantity * 15
      stepOne = 'v1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepTwo = 'v2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepThree = 'v3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepFour = 'v4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepFive = 'v5- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      break;
    case 'Aeropress':
      grindType = 'Medium-Fine'
      gramsOfWater = cupQuantity * 90
      gramsOfCoffee = cupQuantity * 15
      stepOne = 'a1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepTwo = 'a2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepThree = 'a3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepFour = 'a4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepFive = 'a5- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      break;
    case 'Cold Brew':
      grindType = 'Extra-Coarse'
      gramsOfWater = cupQuantity * 212
      gramsOfCoffee = cupQuantity * 15
      stepOne = 'cb1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepTwo = 'cb2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepThree = 'cb3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepFour = 'cb4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      stepFive = 'cb5- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.';
      break;
    default:
      grindType = 'error'
  }
});

// Make dropdown menu display selected text
// Doesn't work bc node doesn't have DOM
// $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
//   $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
//   $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
// });

// Separate Page Results
app.get('/results', function(req, res) {
  res.render('results', {
    brewType: brewTypeResult,
    cupQuantity: cupQuantityResult,
    gramsOfWater: gramsOfWater,
    gramsOfCoffee: gramsOfCoffee,
    grindType: grindType,
    stepOne: stepOne,
    stepTwo: stepTwo,
    stepThree: stepThree,
    stepFour: stepFour,
    stepFive: stepFive
  });
});

app.post("/results", function(req, res) {
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on port 8000.");
});
```

input.ejs

```
<div class="container input-grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-lg-4 left-column'>
      <div class="row">
        <h1 class="title-blurb">Coffee Ratio Calculator</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="title-blurb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 right-column">
      <div class="box">
        <form class="calculator-input" action="/" method="post">
          <div class="top-group">
            <div class="row input-row">
              <h2>Select Your Brew Method</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row input-row brew-input">
              <select class="brew-input" name="brewType" id="brewType">
                <option>Filter</option>
                <option>French Press</option>
                <option>V60</option>
                <option>Aeropress</option>
                <option>Cold Brew</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-row row">
            <h2>How many cups?</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="row cup-input">
            <input class="cup-input" type="number" id="quantity" name="cupQuantity" min="1" max="10">
          </div>
          <div class="button-row calc-button">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg buttons">Calculate</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
</div>

<%-include('partials/footer')%>
```

results.ejs

```
<div class="container input-grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 left-column">
      <div class="row">
        <h1 class="title-blurb">Coffee Ratio Calculator</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="title-blurb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 right-column">
      <form action="/" method="post">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="results-data">
            <div class="row results-row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="results-title">Brew Method:</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="results-right"><%= brewType %></h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row results-row'>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="results-title">Cup Quantity:</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="results-right"><%= cupQuantity %></h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row results-row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="results-title">Grind Type:</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="results-right"> <%= grindType %> </h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row results-row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="results-title">Grams of Coffee:</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="results-right"><%= gramsOfCoffee %> g</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="results-title">Grams of Water:</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="results-right"> <%= gramsOfWater %> g</h2>
              </div>
            </div>


            <%# Back Button %>
            <div class="button-row">
              <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg buttons backButton" role="button" aria-disabled="true">Back</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="brewInstructions">
    <h2 class="instructionsTitle"><%= brewType %> Coffee Instructions</h2>
    <div class="instructions">
      <ol>
        <li>
          <%= stepOne %>
        </li>
        <br>
        <li>
          <%= stepTwo %>
        </li>
        <br>
        <li>
          <%= stepThree %>
        </li>
        <br>
        <li>
          <%= stepFour %>
        </li>
        <br>
        <li>
          <%= stepFive %>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>


  </div>

  <%-include('partials/footer')%>
```

I am confused on how to convert the app.post to react format and if I can still use the variables <%= %>. I am a beginner and trying to build my portfolio site through react and connect previous projects I have done. Thank you for any help!

I tried to create new react files and copy and paste code in as it seemed to work. I kept coming up with errors and am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UI Only Solution**

The data needed for your calculator (e.g. the steps) is hard-coded into your JS code. So you can do the calculation in the React UI without the need of a backend.

This is what the react component could look like:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

/** the React component */
export const CoffeeCalculator = () => {

  /** the variables which were input to your calculator POST */
  const [brewType, setBrewType] = useState('Filter');
  const [cupQuantity, setCupQuantity] = useState(1);

  /** the variables which will be set during the calucaltion */
  const [grindType, setGrindType] = useState(null);
  const [gramsOfWater, setGramsOfWater] = useState(null);
  const [gramsOfCoffee, setGramsOfCoffee] = useState(null);
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState([]);

  /** gets executed everytime brewType or cupQuantity changes */
  useEffect(() => {
    // this is the same logic you had in your Node.js express POST
    switch (brewType) {
      case 'Filter':
        setGrindType('Medium');
        setGramsOfWater(cupQuantity * 235);
        setGramsOfCoffee(cupQuantity * 14);
        setSteps([
          'f1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f5- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
        ])
        break;
      case 'French Press':
        setGrindType('Coarse');
        setGramsOfWater(cupQuantity * 350);
        setGramsOfCoffee(cupQuantity * 30);
        setSteps([
          'f1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f5- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
        ]);
        break;
      case 'V60':
        setGrindType('Medium-Coarse');
        setGramsOfWater(cupQuantity * 250);
        setGramsOfCoffee(cupQuantity * 15);
        setSteps([
          'f1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f5- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
        ]);
        break;
      case 'Aeropress':
        setGrindType('Medium-Fine');
        setGramsOfWater(cupQuantity * 90);
        setGramsOfCoffee(cupQuantity * 15);
        setSteps([
          'f1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f5- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
        ]);
        break;
      case 'Cold Brew':
        setGrindType('Extra-Coarse');
        setGramsOfWater(cupQuantity * 212);
        setGramsOfCoffee(cupQuantity * 15);
        setSteps([
          'f1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
          'f5- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.',
        ]);
        break;
      default:
        setGrindType('error');
    }
  }, [brewType, cupQuantity]);


  return (
    <>
      <div className="container input-grid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className='col-lg-4 left-column'>
            <div className="row">
              <h1 className="title-blurb">Coffee Ratio Calculator</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <p className="title-blurb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-8 right-column">
            <div className="box">
              <form className="calculator-input" action="/" method="post">
                <div className="top-group">
                  <div className="row input-row">
                    <h2>Select Your Brew Method</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row input-row brew-input">
                    <select className="brew-input" name="brewType" id="brewType" value={brewType} onChange={event => setBrewType(event.target.value)}>
                      <option>Filter</option>
                      <option>French Press</option>
                      <option>V60</option>
                      <option>Aeropress</option>
                      <option>Cold Brew</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="input-row row">
                  <h2>How many cups?</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="row cup-input">
                  <input className="cup-input" type="number" id="quantity" name="cupQuantity" min="1" max="10"  value={cupQuantity} onChange={event => setCupQuantity(parseInt(event.target.value))} />
                </div>
                <div className="button-row calc-button">
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg buttons">Calculate</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/*The output - only show if there is a result*/}
        <div className={'row'}>
          <div className={'col'}>
            <div className="box">
              <div className="results-data">
                <div className="row results-row">
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="results-title">Brew Method:</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="results-right">
                      {brewType}
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className='row results-row'>
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="results-title">Cup Quantity:</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="results-right">
                      {cupQuantity}
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row results-row">
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="results-title">Grind Type:</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="results-right">
                      {grindType}
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row results-row">
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="results-title">Grams of Coffee:</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="results-right">
                      {gramsOfCoffee} g
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="results-title">Grams of Water:</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="results-right">
                      {gramsOfWater} g
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/*the steps*/}
        <div className={'row'}>
          <div className={'col'}>
            <div className="brewInstructions">
              <h2 className="instructionsTitle">
                {brewType} Coffee Instructions
              </h2>
              <div className="instructions">
                <ol>
                  {/*iterate through the steps to create a <li> element for each step*/}
                  {
                    steps.map(instruction => {
                      return (
                        <li>
                          {instruction}
                        </li>
                      )
                    })
                  }
                </ol>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

The input and output of the calculator are all in one component. The output is recalculated every time the input changes.

Key differences to the EJS script are:

- we are using [React state hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for all input and output variables (`useState()`)
- we are using [React effect hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for the actual calculation (`useEffect()`). This is executed every time `brewType` or `setCupQuantity` is changed.
- We can deploy the state variables and any other javascript to the html by using curly braces: `{grindType}`.

---

**UI + Backend Solution**

In case you *do* need a backend integration you can use [standard AJAX to retrieve the data](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) from the backend.

For instance, you could save the steps to brew coffee in a backend database.

You can re-use your existing Node.js express app with the following changes:

Enable express to parse `json`:

`app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Modify the url of your endpoint to start with `/api`. This will allow us to host the React app and the express REST API on the same domain:

```
app.post("/api/calculate", function(req, res) {
    const brewType = req.body.brewType;
    const cupQuantity = req.body.cupQuantity;

    console.log("brew type: " + brewType);
    console.log("cups: " + cupQuantity);

    let brewTypeResult = brewType;
    let cupQuantityResult = cupQuantity;

    res.redirect("/results");

    switch (brewTypeResult) {
      ...
    }

    // return result as json
    res.json({
      grindType: grindType,
      gramsOfWater: gramsOfWater,
      gramsOfCoffee: gramsOfCoffee,
      steps: stepsArray
    });
}
```

Make sure that your React development server proxies all AJAX requests to `/api` to your express app. Add this to your React's `package.json`:

`"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"`

At last, you can use any AJAX library to fetch the data in your UI `useEffect` calculator function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/coffee-calculate', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        brewType: brewType,
        cupQuantity: cupQuantity,
      })
    })
      .then(async response => {
        // parse the response's data to JSON
        const json = await response.json();
        // assign result to local state
        setGrindType(json.grindType);
        setGramsOfWater(json.gramsOfWater);
        setGramsOfCoffee(json.gramsOfCoffee);
        setSteps(json.steps);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle any AJAX errors
      })
  }, [brewType, cupQuantity])
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I changed up your code a bit, but it definitely got me on the right track! I really appreciate it Christoph!

Answer (score 1):

this is what I ended up doing. i added a ternary statement attached to the onClick function for the button to render different results based on if the calculator had received input yet. big thanks for christoph for pointing me in the right direction!

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

//styles for grid
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    boxShadow: '0px 0px 0px',
}));

function CoffeeCalculator() {
    const [isCalculated, setIsCalculated] = useState(false);

    const [brewType, setBrewType] = useState('Filter');
    const [cupQuantity, setCupQuantity] = useState(1);

    const [grindType, setGrindType] = useState(null);
    const [gramsOfWater, setGramsOfWater] = useState(null);
    const [gramsOfCoffee, setGramsOfCoffee] = useState(null);
    const [steps, setSteps] = useState([]);

    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsCalculated(!isCalculated);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        switch (brewType) {
            case 'Filter':
                setGrindType('Medium');
                setGramsOfWater(cupQuantity * 235);
                setGramsOfCoffee(cupQuantity * 14);
                setSteps([
                    'Filter step1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'Filter step2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'Filter step3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'Filter step4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'Filter step5- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'Filter step6- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                ]);
                break;
            case 'French Press':
                setGrindType('Coarse');
                setGramsOfWater(cupQuantity * 350);
                setGramsOfCoffee(cupQuantity * 30);
                setSteps([
                    'French Press step1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'French Press step2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'French Press step3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'French Press step4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                ]);
                break;
            case 'V60':
                setGrindType('Medium-Coarse');
                setGramsOfWater(cupQuantity * 250);
                setGramsOfCoffee(cupQuantity * 15);
                setSteps([
                    'V60 step1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'V60 step2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'V60 step3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'V60 step4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'V60 step5- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                ]);
                break;
            case 'Aeropress':
                setGrindType('Medium-Fine');
                setGramsOfWater(cupQuantity * 90);
                setGramsOfCoffee(cupQuantity * 15);
                setSteps([
                    'Aeropress step1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'Aeropress step2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'Aeropress step3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                ]);
                break;
            case 'Cold Brew':
                setGrindType('Extra-Coarse');
                setGramsOfWater(cupQuantity * 212);
                setGramsOfCoffee(cupQuantity * 15);
                setSteps([
                    'Cold Brew step1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'Cold Brew step2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'Cold Brew step3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                    'Cold Brew step4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
                ]);
                break;
            default:
                setGrindType('error');
        }
    }, [brewType, cupQuantity]);

    function InputCoffeeCalc() {
        return (
            <Grid item lg={8} className='right-column'>
                <Item>
                    <div className='box'>
                        <form
                            className='calculator-input'
                            action='/'
                            method='post'
                        >
                            <div className='top-group'>
                                <h2 className='input-row'>
                                    Select Your Brew Method
                                </h2>
                                <select
                                    className='brew-input'
                                    name='brewType'
                                    id='brewType'
                                    value={brewType}
                                    onChange={(event) =>
                                        setBrewType(event.target.value)
                                    }
                                >
                                    <option>Filter</option>
                                    <option>French Press</option>
                                    <option>V60</option>
                                    <option>Aeropress</option>
                                    <option>Cold Brew</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <h2 className='input-row'>How many cups?</h2>
                            <input
                                className='cup-input'
                                type='number'
                                id='quantity'
                                name='cupQuantity'
                                min='1'
                                max='10'
                                value={cupQuantity}
                                onChange={(event) =>
                                    setCupQuantity(parseInt(event.target.value))
                                }
                            />
                            <div className='button-row'>
                                <button
                                    type='submit'
                                    className='buttons calc-button'
                                    onClick={handleClick}
                                >
                                    Calculate
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </Item>
            </Grid>
        );
    }

    function ResultsCoffeeCalc() {
        function ResultsRow(props) {
            return (
                <Grid container item spacing={0} className='results-row'>
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <Grid item md={8} sm={12}>
                            <Item>
                                <h2 className='results-left'>{props.data}</h2>
                            </Item>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item md={4} sm={12}>
                            <Item>
                                <h2 className='results-right'>
                                    {props.results}
                                </h2>
                            </Item>
                        </Grid>
                    </React.Fragment>
                </Grid>
            );
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='box'>
                    <Grid
                        item
                        // lg={12}
                        container
                        spacing={-20}
                        className='results-data'
                    >
                        <ResultsRow data='Brew Method:' results={brewType} />
                        <ResultsRow
                            data='Cup Quantity:'
                            results={cupQuantity}
                        />
                        <ResultsRow data='Grind Type:' results={grindType} />
                        <ResultsRow
                            data='Grams of Coffee:'
                            results={gramsOfCoffee}
                        />
                        <ResultsRow
                            data='Grams of Water:'
                            results={gramsOfWater}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <div className='button-row'>
                        <button
                            type='submit'
                            className='buttons calc-button'
                            onClick={handleClick}
                        >
                            Back
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <BrewInstructions />
            </div>
        );
    }

    function BrewInstructions() {
        return (
            <div className='brewInstructions'>
                <h2 className='instructionsTitle'>
                    {brewType} Coffee Instructions
                </h2>
                <div className='instructions'>
                    <ol>
                        {/*iterate through the steps to create a <li> element for each step*/}
                        {steps.map((step) => {
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    <li>{step}</li>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Box
                sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                className='coffee-calculator-page input-grid'
            >
                <Grid container spacing={-20}>
                    <Grid item lg={4} className='left-column'>
                        <Item>
                            <h1 className='title title-blurb'>
                                Coffee Ratio Calculator
                            </h1>
                            <p className='title-blurb'>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                                adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eu
                                volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.{' '}
                            </p>
                        </Item>
                    </Grid>
                    {/* returns different results based on calculation input */}
                    <Grid item lg={8}>
                        <Item>
                            {isCalculated ? (
                                <ResultsCoffeeCalc />
                            ) : (
                                <InputCoffeeCalc />
                            )}
                        </Item>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Box>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CoffeeCalculator;
```